# How to prevent keep add string to the object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When click on run button each time Mi string adding how to prevent
Result : 1000MiMi
Expected result multiple time click : 1000Mi

```
function App() {
      let memory = [{size:1000}]
      const handleSubmit = () =>{
        memory.map((item) => {
          const manju =  item.size + 'Mi'
          item.size = manju 
          return item
        })
        console.log(memory)
      }
      return (<div>
    <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Run</button>
        </div>)
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. Here you're directly modifying each object in `memory` (and throwing away the result of the `map` operation)--if you don't want to modify it twice, don't keep modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to prevent `item.size` from repeatedly adding 'Mi' onto the end, trying using the `.endsWith()` method.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    memory.map((item) => {
      if (!(item.size+"").endsWith("Mi")) {
          const manju =  item.size + 'Mi';
      }
      item.size = manju;
      return item;
    });
    console.log(memory);
  }
```

Comment: `manju` is local to the `if` block, you can't refer to it outside the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
memory.map((item) => {
          const manju =  item.size + 'Mi'
          item.size = manju 
          return item
        })
```

you are overwriting the value of item

instead you have to return a new value

like this

```
memory.map((item) => {
   return {size: item.size + 'Mi'}
})
```

Comment: Since he's not using the result of `map()`, this will have no effect.

Comment: I think he wants to modify it in place, just not add multiple `Mi` suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using the result of `map()` for anything, you should use `forEach()` instead.

To prevent multiple `Mi` suffixes, check if it has already been added.

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
  memory.forEach((item) => {
    if (!(item.size + "").endsWith("Mi")) {
      item.size += 'Mi';
    }
  });
  console.log(memory);
}

const memory = [{size: 1000}]
handleSubmit();
memory.push({size: 500});
handleSubmit();
```